# How to put the center div in a flex container as horizontally centered in whole vw

Tags: html, css

I have been stuck in tutorial H311 forever trying to self teach myself. Well I finally decided to just take the plunge and develop something without following a tutorial step-by-step. I first drew out my nav idea for a crm web app in figma:

[image: figma design]

Then i built out the entire nav bar using plain HTML and CSS:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 110vh;
            width: 100vw;
        }

        nav {
            height: 50px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #005b97;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        form {
            color: #555;
            display: flex;
            padding: 2px;
            border: 1px solid currentColor;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        input[type="search"] {
            border: none;
            background: transparent;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 7px 8px;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: inherit;
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            border-radius: inherit;
        }

        input[type="search"]:focus {
            box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #1183d6;
            border-color: #1183d6;
            outline: none;
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        }

        input[type="search"]:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #1183d6;
            border-color: #1183d6;
            outline: none;
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        }

        form.nosubmit {
            border: none;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
            width: 475px;
        }

        input.nosubmit {
            border: 1px solid #555;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 9px 4px 9px 40px;
            background: transparent url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' class='bi bi-search' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E") no-repeat 13px center;
        }

        .appTitle {
            color: white;
            margin-left: 10px;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .appTitle span {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .navLeft {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }

        .ulMainNav {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            margin-left: 10px;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .ulMainNav li {
            display: inline;
            margin-inline: none;
        }

        .mainNavLink {
            color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 13px;
            margin-inline: 5px;
            height: 90%;
            padding-bottom: 9px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .mainNavLink:hover {
            color: white;
            border-bottom: 3px solid white;
        }

        /* Is this the best practice way for handling nav item active status */
        .mainNavLinkActive {
            color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 13px;
            margin-inline: 5px;
            height: 90%;
            padding-bottom: 9px;
            border-bottom: 3px solid white;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .profileDropDown {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            height: 50px;
            padding: 0 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .profileDropDown:hover {
            background-color: #d1d1d1;
        }

        .avatar {
            height: 35px;
            width: 35px;
        }

        .avatar img {
            height: 100%;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }

        .profileDropDown .icons-container i {
            margin-right: 0;
        }

        .navRight {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .icons-container {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .icons-container i {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .icons-container>* {
            margin: 0 5px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/aecb2591bd.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="navLeft">
            <div class="menuToggle">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-bars fa-xl" style="cursor:pointer; color: #ffffff;"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="applicationTitle">
                <span class="appTitle">CRM</span>
            </div>
            <div class="mainNav">
                <ul class="ulMainNav">
                    <li><a href="" class="mainNavLinkActive">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="mainNavLink">Schedule</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="mainNavLink">Clients</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="mainNavLink">Billing</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="navCenter">
            <form class="nosubmit">
                <input class="nosubmit" type="search" placeholder="Search...">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="navRight">

            <div class="icons-container">
                <i class="fa-regular fa-message fa-md" style="color: #b3b3b3;"></i>
                <i class="fa-regular fa-bell fa-md" style="color: #b3b3b3;"></i>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-print fa-md" style="color: #b3b3b3;"></i>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-gear fa-md" style="color: #b3b3b3;"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="profileDropDown">
                <div class="avatar">
                    <img src="guy.jpeg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="icons-container">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down fa-sm profileChevron" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

here is the resulting output:

[image: result]

As you can see, the search input [.navCenter] is not horizontally centered in the navbar. I understand it may look a little funky with no white space on the left and lot's on the right, but that's how i designed it and I'm challenging myself to stick to the design.

I'm not asking for the specific answer, rather, some ideas or thoughts about how I could find resources on how to achieve the desired effect.

I attempted to ask an AI model, and they can usually fix it, but only by affecting the existing layouts of nextLeft and navRight (which are already done)